# Angular 8+ format XML prettyprint No external library

Tags: html, angular, xml, npm, format

I am using Angular 8+ and I want to prettyprint a xml in the right format on the HTML. From the backend (Java) I receive a string and I wanna display this string in html in a XML format without an NPM lib. I wanna use it in a custom pipe but no external library or npms.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use <pre> tag in html?

Comment: added my solution below.

Comment: no <pre> tags in the html

Answer (score 1):

CSS :-

```
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<div>{{xml}}<div>
```

TS:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public xml = `
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <note>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <message>Remember me this weekend</message>
      </note>
  `;
}
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bvr7t

Comment: need stackblitz?

Comment: added stackblitz url above.

Comment: i see, but before the <note> there is a tabspace. If i remove the tabspace, i will not prettyprint succesfully

Comment: have a proper xml from backend and try it.